# JQuery Mobile: how to load jquery mobile page from another html file?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I am pretty new to JQuery Mobile, and I got a problem with loading page from another html files into div:

I got an empty page (main.html) which is a place holder for the pages:

```
<body id="content" style="display: none;">
<!-- This is a placeholder for dynamic page content -->
<div id="pagePort"></div>
</body>
```

I have another html like this:

```
<div data-role="page" id="signin">...</div>
```

I include this script in main.html like this:

```
$("#paegPort").load("signin.html", function(){
                $("#signin").page();
                $("#pagePort").trigger("create");
                $("body").trigger("create");
            });
```

However, I got a blank page.
I am expecting a html like:

```
 <body id="content" style="display: none;">
<!-- This is a placeholder for dynamic page content -->
<div id="pagePort"><div data-role="page" id="signin">...</div></div>
</body>
```

But I got:

```
<body id="content" style="display: block;" class="ui-mobile-viewport ui-overlay-c">
<div data-role="page" data-url="..." tabindex="0" class="ui-page ui-body-c ui-page-active" style="min-height: 208px;">
<!-- This is a placeholder for dynamic page content -->
        <div id="pagePort">
    <div data-role="page" id="signin"...>...</div>
    </div>
</div></body>
```

The program added a line automatically after body:

```
<div data-role="page" data-url="..." tabindex="0" class="ui-page ui-body-c ui-page-active" style="min-height: 208px;">
```

and the page I want to load does not show.

Can anyone help me with that? How to I load a jquery page from file into a div inside body?

Comment: Try the code in this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/7fMKR/

Answer (score 0):

Your javascript has an error. You have #paegPort in the selector.

```
$("#pagePort").load("signin.html", function(){
            $("#signin").page();
            $("#pagePort").trigger("create");
            $("body").trigger("create");
        });
```

I would suggest debugging with chrome's developer tool and see what jquery is pulling accross the network. Can you load the html page that you are trying to load by going directly to it in the browser?